# What are the differences between these three in Jasypt?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I am using Jasypt in Spring Boot.

I have defined Jasypt Configuratoin as below, but I have some questions about configuring the bean.

Currently, I am using PBEStringEncryptor, but there are three types of Encryptor in Maven jar.

I want to know the difference between PBEStringEncryptor, PooledPBEStringEncryptor, and StandardPBEStringEncryptor and when to use which.

And I would like to know what PBE stands for.

```java
@Configuration
public class JasyptConfig  {

    @Bean
    public PBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor() {

        String encryptPwd = "test"
        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();

        config.setPassword(encryptPwd);
        config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
        config.setPoolSize("1");
        config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
        config.setStringOutputType("base64");

        encryptor.setConfig(config);

        return encryptor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBE stands for Password-based encryption.

`PBEStringEncryptor` is an interface. This is your method's return type to enable late binding.

`PooledPBEStringEncryptor` and `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` are implementations on that interface (Well there is another layer between them, but I think we can skip that part). I will mostly be quoting from jasypt's documentation now.

`StandardPBEStringEncryptor` enables a user to specify the algorithm (and provider) to be used for encryption, the password to use, the number of hashing iterations and the salt generator that will be applied for obtaining the encryption key.

`PooledPBEStringEncryptor` is an enhanced version of `StandardPBEStringEncryptor`. Pooled implementation of `PBEStringEncryptor` in fact contains an array of `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` objects which are used to attend encrypt and decrypt requests in round-robin. This should result in higher performance in multiprocessor systems.

For us end users, it would always be better to use `PooledPBEStringEncryptor` unless we're somehow restricting our app to use only one processor. Even then, you won't find any performance difference between these two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer has helped me a lot.